# How to destroy connection in Channel API GAE (python)?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I am creating a channel using channel api on app server using

```
channelId = channel.create_channel('mychannel')
```

now I want to destroy this channel. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel Token [expires in 2 hours](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/#Python_Tokens_and_security) by default. You don't explicitly get to delete a channel from server side, however, from the javascript side you can easily call a [close()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript) method